# Upper-semicontinuous function can be bounded above by a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

**Problem:** Show that for every real-valued upper-semicontinuous function  $f$: $\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ there is a continuous function $g$ : $\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ such that $f \leq g$.

I constructed a few functions, one of them being $g(x)=\max_{x \in [0, x]}f(x)$  for $x \geq 0$ and analogously for negative values but this is not continuous.

Please help I am struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is bounded above, there is a standard construction based on sup-convolutions.
Given $k > 0$, define
$$
g(x) := \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}} \left[f(y) - k|x-y|\right].
$$
Then $g$ is finite, Lipschitz continuous and $g\geq f$.

We can try to modify this construction taking into account the fact that $f$ is bounded above on every compact set, defining
$$
h(x) := \max_{y\in [x-k, x+k]} \left[f(y) - k|x-y|\right].
$$
It should be checked that $h$ is continuous.